# Proving all solutions of $y'+y=f(x)$ are bounded

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $y'+y=f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is continuous and bounded on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that all the solutions of the equation are bounded on $[0,\infty)$.
>
> **Hint**: If $M$ is an upper bound of $|h(x)|$ then $\left |\int\limits_{a}^{b}g(x)h(x)dx \right|\leq M\int\limits_{a}^{b}|g(x)|dx$

*My attempt*: Multiplying both sides by $e^x$ we get $(ye^x)'=e^x f(x)$, therefore $|y(x)|=\left|e^{-x}\left(\int\limits_{x_0}^{x}e^t f(t)dt+C\right)\right|\leq \left|\int\limits_{x_0}^{x}e^t f(t)dt\right|+|C|\leq M \int\limits_{x_0}^{x}|e^t|dt + |C|=Me^x+|C|-Me^{x_0} $ for all $x\in[0,\infty)$. However $Me^x$ is not bounded. Where is my mistake?

Comment: The mistake is multiplying by an unbounded function.:)  Let $M$ be an upper bound for $f$.  Multiply the equation by $y$:
$$
{1 \over 2} (y^2)' + y^2 = yf.
$$
Integrating on both sides from $x_{0}$ to $x_{1}$ w.r.t. $dt$, we get:
$$
{1 \over 2} (y^2)' |^{x_{1}}_{x_{0}} + \int^{x_{1}}_{x_{0}} y^2 dx =  \int|^{x_{1}}_{x_{0}} y  f dx \leq \left| \int^{x_{1}}_{x_{0}} y  f dx \right| \leq 
%M \int^{x_{1}}_{x_{0}} |y| dx
$$
Thus,
$$
{1 \over 2} (y^2)'|^{x_{1}}_{x_{0}} \leq M \int^{x_{1}}_{x_{0}} |y| dx - \int^{x_{1}}_{x_{0}} y^2 dx
$$
If $y$ is unbounded, we get a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be 
\begin{align}
|y(x)|&=\left|e^{-x}\left(\int\limits_{x_0}^{x}e^{t} f(t)dt+C\right)\right|
\\
&\leqslant Me^{-x}\int\limits_{x_0}^{x}e^{t} dt+|C|e^{-x}
\\
&=M(1-e^{x_0-x})+|C|e^{-x}
\\
&\leqslant M|1+e^{x_0}|+|C|
\end{align}
for $x\in[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Why it should be $|y(x)|=\left|\left(\int\limits_{x_0}^{x}e^{t-x} f(t)dt+C\right)\right|$?